How do I export a D3 chart as a png using html2canvas with the correct custom fonts?
I have several chart components written in D3.js in Vue 3 and I have a separate component which is a button that exports a singular chart as a PNG using html2canvas. The exporting works fine but I use Poppins as the font for things like legends and axis labels in the charts but this is not exported correctly.
This is my code to export the charts:
const vm = this
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(this.chartID), {
          scale: vm.exportImageScale,
          scrollY: -window.scrollY,
          backgroundColor: '#121111',
        }).then((canvas) => {
          downloadLink(canvas.toDataURL(), `${this.downloadName}.png`)
        })

I tried using html-to-image instead but i ended up getting lots of 429 errors trying to access the fonts.

To make sure Poppins font is displayed in the chart, you need to first load the font before capturing the chart.
const vm = this
const font = new FontFaceObserver('Poppins');
font.load().then(() => {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById(vm.chartID), {
    scale: vm.exportImageScale,
    scrollY: -window.scrollY,
    backgroundColor: '#121111',
    useCORS: true, 
  }).then((canvas) => {
    downloadLink(canvas.toDataURL(), `${vm.downloadName}.png`);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error loading font:', error);
});

